# Queria saber a diferença entre a presença e a ausência da primeira condição do código abaixo

Tags: php, sql, query

Tenho um código que peguei em algum lugar, faz algum tempo, que uso para fazer as conexões com os meus banco de dados e ele sempre funcionou bem. Tentei , então, retirar um trecho de código que eu não entendia e, pra minha surpresa, continuou funcionando.. ou era o que eu pensava.
Ao longo do  projeto, me vi obrigado a usar a função lastInsertId(), do PHP, mas sempre me retornava 0, independendo do comando que eu tentasse executar antes no banco de dados. Passei muito tempo até entender que o que faltava pro código funcionar como eu queria, retornando o valor do último id inserido na tabela daquele banco de dados, era a linha de código que eu tinha retirado, que é uma condição.

Abaixo, o código que funciona:

```
class MySql{
private static $pdo;

protected function MySql(){
    if (self::$pdo == null) {
        try {
            self::$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.BD['host'].';dbname='.BD['name'],BD['user'],BD['password'],array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo '<h2>Erro ao conectar</h2>';
        }
    }
    return self::$pdo;
}
```

}

Agora, o que não funciona:

```
class MySql{
private static $pdo;

protected function MySql(){
        try {
            self::$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.BD['host'].';dbname='.BD['name'],BD['user'],BD['password'],array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo '<h2>Erro ao conectar</h2>';
        }
    return self::$pdo;
}
```

}

Agora, o que eu usei pra tentar pegar o último id:

```
$sql = $this->MySql()->prepare("$query");
$sql->execute($parametros);
$ultimo_id = $this->MySql()->lastInsertId();
```

Onde $query é uma query qualquer de inserção e $parametros é um array contendo os valores - obviamente, a tabela deve ter uma chave primária, a qual eu sempre chamo de 'id'.
O primeiro código funciona bem, enquanto que o segundo sempre retorna 0. A única diferença entre eles é a condição if.
Eu queria entender qual a diferença entre os dois e porque acontece essa diferença. Agradeço se alguém puder me explicar.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está suficientemente objetiva. Organize da seguinte maneira:
1) O que eu espero que aconteça
2) O que acontece
3) Minha dúvida do motivo de acontecer

Capriche no título. Tente colocar o título o mais técnico possível. Fale de funções, classes, variáveis, e não condição A ou B. Garanto que vamos poder ajudar melhor!

Comment: `if (self::$pdo == null) {` esse if basicamente é para garantir que só haja uma instância da variável `$pdo`, que é `static` por sinal e faz todo sentido, ou seja, só instancia uma vez se for null, para evitar conectar ao banco sempre